# Endforeach block in PHP breaks indent. I want to write templates simply

Tags: php

I have a trouble when I write template file in php. I want to ajust 'header' and 'headerend' at same indent.

```
> php main.php
start
    header
            mike
            jane
        headerend
end
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

include __DIR__ . '/indent-foreach-borken.php';
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$users = ['mike', 'jane'];
?>
start
    <?= 'header' . PHP_EOL ?>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <?= $user . PHP_EOL ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    headerend
end
```

I have achieved it with using PHP_EOL, but it makes the template complicated.

```
> php main.php
start
    header
            mike
            jane
    headerend
end
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

include __DIR__ . '/indent-foreach.php';
```

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

$users = ['mike', 'jane'];
$lastUser = end($users);
?>
start
    <?= 'header' . PHP_EOL ?>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
        <?= $user ?><?php if ($user !== $lastUser): ?><?= PHP_EOL ?><?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?><?= PHP_EOL ?>
    headerend
end
```

Must I write complexly? Do people write it such as this complex?

Comment: First of all, I understand the desire to make nice-looking HTML output, but try to get out of that mindset. It makes zero difference to browsers how much whitespace you have, and you can drive yourself nuts and waste so much time trying to make it look nice when you are the only person that's ever going to know it. You can get rid of some of that, though, by putting your `<?php` tags for the control structures at the left margin; you've got spaces before you open the PHP code, and all of that is preserved.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank you very much for your comment.

> you've got spaces before you open the PHP code, and all of that is preserved.

I see. Is there no way I want? We must join 'endforeach' and 'headerend'. I must not make newline and spaces between both.

Comment: "at the left margin" means "I must remove one indent before headerend"? Is it in CSS?

Comment: Still not understanding why you "must" get the spacing like that. I've explained that HTML doesn't care what the spacing is. So, either the "must" requirement is something that you are self-imposing for no good reason, in which case the solution is to free yourself from that artificial limitation by just ignoring what the HTML looks like, or else there's some external requirement that you haven't explained, in which case knowing what that is would probably help us to solve your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I want the spaces(indent) to make generator. I preserve pretty in generated code. I will edit the code.